# Keep encountering "string index out of range' error in Python

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment for an intro course in which I need to determine whether a string is a palindrome. Having trouble with this segment of the code:

```
    def is_palindrome(letters): 
         if (len(letters))==0:
             return True
         elif len(letters)==1:
             return True
         elif (letters[end])==(letters[0]):
            return is_palindrome(letters[(letters[0+1]):(letters[len(letters)-1])])
         else:
            return False
```

Comment: 1. I feel like `return is_palindrome(letters[(letters[0+1]):(letters[len(letters)-1])])` should be `return is_palindrome(letters[1:-1])` . 2. `def is_palindrome(letters): return letters == letters[::-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nearly correct, but you have errors in the slicing of the strings:

```
def is_palindrome(letters): 
    if (len(letters))==0:
        return True
    elif len(letters)==1:
        return True
    elif (letters[0])==(letters[-1]):       # index [-1] gives the last letter
        return is_palindrome(letters[1:-1]) # slice [1:-1] is the word without the first and last letter.
    else:
        return False
```

The above works.

I suggest you review this post that explains in details how slicing works: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: great resource. the link helped out a friend who was struggling with the splicing. +1

Comment: @OliverChild-Lanning Now you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try these following codes:

```
def palindrome(text):
    if text == text[::-1]:
        print(text, 'is palindrome')
    else:
        print(text, 'is not palindrome')

palindrome('reser')
palindrome('reset')
```

`str[::-1]` will reverse the string. for more info, try `help(slice)`.

Comment: This is a different method than what the OP tried - of course, it works, but does it teach him to correct his mistake?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Well, I think this way is more clearer and simpler. However you've just post an answer that correct his mistake ;)

Comment: Your code as it is returns erroneous answers - please fix it. :)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Finished, I forgot change `str[::1]` to `str[::-1]`. Thanks :)